# Solr lib directories outside of local path

Tags: solr

I've got a solr config directory in my project's repository that looks like this:

```
solr
└── collection1
    ├── conf
    │   ├── schema.xml
    │   ├── solrconfig.xml
    │   └── ...
    └── data
        └── ...
```

I've pretty much copied everything in there from the example directory from my
solr installation (solr 4.5.0 installed via [homebrew](http://brew.sh) on mac os x).

The `solrconfig.xml` references a number of libraries in the installation
directory:

```
<lib dir="../../../contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

<lib dir="../../../contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />
```

These of course aren't loaded correctly because they are relative to the
installation directory, and not my repo.

**Can I reference the installation directory in `solrconfig.xml` without
hard-coding the path?** I could just do:

```
<lib dir="/usr/local/Cellar/solr/4.5.0/libexec/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

But that's not very portable.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? Upvoted +!

Comment: naw. i added a step in my build system to make a link from the local lib to the installation dir (w/ platform-specific logic), and made that step a pre-req to starting up the solr server (bummer).